# Configure Apache to use a different user in specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I'm currently trying to configure Apache so it will use a certain user and group only when in a certain directory.

For example, if accessing RoundCube (for which I use a /mail alias configured in conf-available meaning RoundCube can be accessed from **all sites**, it is stored in /opt/roundcube), Apache should use the www-data user.  However, if accessing any other section of the site (which will be stored in /var/www/...), Apache should use the User and Group directives in the respective sites-available.  The issue however, is sites-available is of higher priority then conf-available meaning when two User or Group directives are encountered (one in conf and one in sites), the sites-available directive is used.

The fact RoundCube can be accessed from all sites is where the issue lies, since I use site-specific users (for example example.com uses the user exmpl) and RoundCube does not have permission to read the configuration file (since of course the file is owned by www-data and the wrong user is trying to access the file).

Comment: Probably you should use virtual hosts instead

Comment: Hi, I have multiple .conf files inside my /sites-available folder (one per website) with each file containing a VirtualHost for each subdomain of the website.  Are you referring to using a VirtualHost for RoundCube mail i.e each site would have a mail subdomain?